# How to display titles of cells from json file + server?

Tags: arrays, swift, tableview

I need to display 12 cells in tableView. Titles of the first 4 cells are taken from json file (it's legacy code). For example:

```
case WatchesCell.NowWatching.rawValue:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithRatingWideTableViewCell",
                                             for: indexPath) as! PosterWithRatingWideTableViewCell
    
    cell.setupSectionTitle("now_watching".localized.uppercased(), viewModel.nowWatchingList.count == 0)
    return cell
```

Other 8 cells (their titles) should be displayed from server. I successfully fetched data in mainCategories array (checked in print), but can't display them in tableView. I got **Fatal error: Index out of range: file Swift/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444** Could you please say what's wrong?

```
enum WatchesCell: Int, CaseIterable {
    case NowWatching = 0
    case Premiers
    case Recommendations
    case Popular
    case Documentary
    case TVShow
    case Educational
    case InfoAnalitycal
    case InfoEntertainment
    case Journalism
    case Cultural
    case Movies
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
               numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return WatchesCell.allCases.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let section = viewModel.mainCategories[indexPath.row].localized_name

switch indexPath.row {

case WatchesCell.NowWatching.rawValue:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithRatingWideTableViewCell",
                                             for: indexPath) as! PosterWithRatingWideTableViewCell
    
    cell.setupSectionTitle("now_watching".localized.uppercased(), viewModel.nowWatchingList.count == 0)
    return cell
    
case WatchesCell.Premiers.rawValue:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithTitleTableViewCell",
                                             for: indexPath) as! PosterWithTitleTableViewCell
    cell.setupSectionTitle("premiers".localized.uppercased(), viewModel.premieres.count == 0)
    return cell
    
case WatchesCell.Recommendations.rawValue:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithRatingWideTableViewCell",
                                             for: indexPath) as! PosterWithRatingWideTableViewCell
    
    cell.setupSectionTitle("recommendations".localized.uppercased(), viewModel.recommendations.count == 0)
    return cell

case WatchesCell.Popular.rawValue:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithRatingWideTableViewCell",
                                                 for: indexPath) as! PosterWithRatingWideTableViewCell
        cell.setupSectionTitle("popular".localized.uppercased(), viewModel.populars.count == 0)
        return cell
        
    //**Here's start cells, which should be displayed from server**:

    case WatchesCell.Documentary.rawValue:
        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithTitleTableViewCell",
                                                 for: indexPath) as! PosterWithTitleTableViewCell
        cell.setupSectionTitle(section.localized.uppercased(), viewModel.documentary.count == 0)
        //print("Section 5: \(section)")
        return cell
```

> ```
>     case WatchesCell.TVShow.rawValue:
>
>         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithTitleTableViewCell",
>                                                  for: indexPath) as! PosterWithTitleTableViewCell
>         cell.setupSectionTitle(section.localized.uppercased(), viewModel.tvShow.count == 0)
>         //print("Section 6: \(section)")
>         return cell
>
>     case WatchesCell.Educational.rawValue:
>
>         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithTitleTableViewCell",
>                                                  for: indexPath) as! PosterWithTitleTableViewCell
>         cell.setupSectionTitle(section.localized.uppercased(), viewModel.educational.count == 0)
>         //print("Section 7: \(section)")
>         return cell
>
>     case WatchesCell.InfoAnalitycal.rawValue:
>
>         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithTitleTableViewCell",
>                                                  for: indexPath) as! PosterWithTitleTableViewCell
>         cell.setupSectionTitle(section.localized.uppercased(), viewModel.infoAnalytical.count == 0)
>         //print("Section 8: \(section)")
>         return cell
>
>     case WatchesCell.InfoEntertainment.rawValue:
>
>         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithTitleTableViewCell",
>                                                  for: indexPath) as! PosterWithTitleTableViewCell
>         cell.setupSectionTitle(section.localized.uppercased(), viewModel.infoEntertainment.count == 0)
>         //print("Section 9: \(section)")
>         return cell
>
>     case WatchesCell.Journalism.rawValue:
>
>         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithTitleTableViewCell",
>                                                  for: indexPath) as! PosterWithTitleTableViewCell
>         cell.setupSectionTitle(section.localized.uppercased(), viewModel.journalism.count == 0)
>         //print("Section 10: \(section)")
>         return cell
>
>     case WatchesCell.Cultural.rawValue:
>
>         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithTitleTableViewCell",
>                                                  for: indexPath) as! PosterWithTitleTableViewCell
>         cell.setupSectionTitle(section.localized.uppercased(), viewModel.cultural.count == 0)
>         //print("Section 11: \(section)")
>         return cell
>
>     case WatchesCell.Movies.rawValue:
>
>         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithTitleTableViewCell",
>                                                  for: indexPath) as! PosterWithTitleTableViewCell
>         cell.setupSectionTitle(section.localized.uppercased(), viewModel.movies.count == 0)
>         //print("Section 12: \(section)")
>         return cell
> ```
>
> default:
> return UITableViewCell()
> }

I also tried to fill these 8 titles like the first 4, from json file, and all cells with content are displayed but I need to show titles dynamically, from server.

Comment: The above code which you shared with `switch indexPath.row` looks incomplete. The switch case is incomplete. You need to handle all the cases. Please share the entire code block of `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` for better understanding.

Comment: Added whole code of cellForRow

Comment: Can you tell us which code is at line no 444 in your project where you are facing this issue? Can you share that articular

Comment: default:
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }

Comment: Could this error may be related to tableView.reloadData?

Comment: It's very difficult to say what's wrong with your code by seeing the code in the piece. Your line number code says something else and you have shared something else. It would be great if you can update your question with a proper code snippet of the table view.

Comment: try adding this code at the start of the `cellForRowAt`.
```
if !viewModel.mainCategories.indices.contains(indexPath.row) {
    return UITableViewCell()
}
let section = viewModel.mainCategories[indexPath.row].localized_name
```

Comment: Error gone but it displays 7 cell instead of 12

Comment: Is it possible for you to add the entire UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate on `https://gist.github.com/` and share the link here?

Answer (score 1):

In your question `cellForRowAt` function is incomplete. If that's your current code what you have in the project. The issue for **fatal error: Index out of range** makes sense.
Your switch case doesn't handle all the index paths scenarios.
Your `cellForRowAt` should look like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let section = viewModel.mainCategories[indexPath.row].localized_name
    switch indexPath.row {
    case WatchesCell.NowWatching.rawValue:
        // Your Code
    case WatchesCell.Premiers.rawValue:
        // Your Code
    case WatchesCell.Recommendations.rawValue:
        // Your Code
    case WatchesCell.Popular.rawValue:
        // Your Code
    case default:
        // Handle all you code for 8 titles which should be displayed from server
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PosterWithTitleTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PosterWithTitleTableViewCell
        cell.setupSectionTitle(section.localized.uppercased(), viewModel.documentary.count == 0)
        print("Section: \(section)")
        return cell
    }
}
```

If your `indexPath.row` will be anything other than the top 4 indexes, then it will go into the `default` switch case.

Comment: Hi! It seems you was right. It displays all sections correctly only the first time data loads, then it adds 8 black cells. Could you please help me how I should handle all 8 titles? When I add second cell after your code, it shows error "Definition conflicts with previous value"

Comment: @Abrcd18 it would be a great help if you can share the screenshot of the screen.

Comment: fixed the error, it was related with loading data

Comment: Sounds Great 